# Android in-app billing is returning server response code 2. What does it mean?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm using In-App Billing V3.
When I try to make a purchase I'm getting a server response code of 2.
I've searched but can find no documentation on what this response code means.

If you look at the official [In-app Billing Reference (IAB Version 3)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) documentation you'll notice 
a value of 2 is conspicuously missing from the table of server response codes.

What does this value indicate, and why might I be getting it??

---

Update:
I've just notice that the documents for [In-app Billing V2](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_reference.html) say that a value of 2 "Indicates that the network connection is down". I'm guessing this is the same in V3, but there's just an omission in the documentation? Can anybody confirm?

---

Update 2:

It looks like the In-App Billing V3 documentation has finally been updated to include the missing server response.

```
BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE     2    Network connection is down
```

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to figure this out eventually? I'm getting the same and I'm not sure why. I have wifi enabled, the app works fine (it retrieves data from the webservice). Any suggestions ?

Comment: I had the same problem, and my network was just fine as well. In my case the problem was actually that I had not enabled the product in the dashboard. This error (in my case) was also accompanied by the error "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account"