# Google inapp billing not working anymore after successfully integrated

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Sorry if this not the place for this issue.

I've just started using inapp billing and I'm having trouble with three inapp products. 
This items are
X Pack
Y Pack
Z Pack

I've set up a test account to simulate the real purchase flow and I cancelled the purchases after I saw that were working properly. But now I cannot purchase the items using the test account (gmail email address (different from developer account) added to test accounts in Google Developer Console). The X Pack doesn't even launch the purchase dialog from Google Play and for the other two I get displayed the message "The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found". What can I do to make it working again?

Comment: Check if the apk is activated on google developer console and you are using the same apk on device

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar "item not found" problem. I've been debugging my code further and can see I'm getting an in-app billing server response code of 2, which is undefined for in-app billing v3, but meant "network connection is down" in v2 as per [my question from a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754209/android-in-app-billing-is-returning-server-response-code-2-what-does-it-mean). So I'm thinking it may be a problem at Google Play's end.

Comment: Now it seems that the problem got away and was fixed by itself. It took some time for Google Play to finish processing the apk and to somehow link the products with the apk. I am using the same apk that I published to Google Play Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

I had two test apps, one exhibiting this problem and the other not. The only difference I could find was one of the apps was "Published" (on Alpha only) and the other was still in "Draft" mode. I filled in the remaining fields to bring it from "Draft" to "Ready to Publish", added Alpha testers, and "Published" on alpha. I had to wait a bit for Google to put the app in store (again for alpha testers only) and it works again.

Google's documentation still says testing In-App Billing with test accounts should work in "Draft" mode, but that definitely stopped working for me.

Comment: I've just received an email from Google Developers saying that the app MUST be published in order to test real purchases, but that does not fix the the problem for `queryInventoryAsynch`. This API call fails because one of the items purchased using a test account remained stuck at purchase state 0 (purchased) and it cannot be consumed or purchased again. So the new query for owned items fails with a "invalid signature" error.